# Linux Desktop app: How can I check a package icon?

Tags: linux, bash, icons, zenity, freedesktop.org

Apparently, one can refer to a program's icon solely by its name, like here:

```
zenity --question --text "Hello <b>world</b>"  --icon-name "baobab"
```

Try replacing `baobab` with `gnome-terminal` and the icon will change, you may even drop the quotes. Obviously there is some kind of abstraction at work here (I like those) with a database. (I know about .desktop files, and the xdg tools][1](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xdg/desktop-file-utils/). But is there a CLI to display (of even **more** hefpul: *don't display it if not found*, *throwing an **error***)) those icons in such a way, like `eog baobab`? (doesn't work.) I want to do that, display the icon of the program I' displaying, sometimes said programs come from larger packages, so I have no real way to know if it's installed.

- How can I know that the icon has not been found (important)?
- How can I get a list of all those "installed" icons?
- How can I test like `chk_icon "baobab" ; $?=0`OK
- How can I test like `chk_icon "installed stuff" ; $?=0`OK

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of tools to help you with this but you are talking about and looking for the freedesktop.org Icon Theme specification I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add a new recognized icon name by copying my icons to the various /usr/share/icons/gnome directories, by size, and THEN running 
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome
without which the icon will still not be recognized.